# ListView getView() called too often

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have a `ListView` with custom `Adapter`. To be honest, I have many of them at the same time on screen, and my Tegra 3 device started to lag, what made me really confused... I found than in each `ListView`'s `Adapter` the `getView()` method is called for all visible rows **every** time **any** animations runs on screen. That gives me like few hundreds of calls per second! Digging more, most of these calls are due to `measure()` and `onMeasure()` calls of `ListView`s' parents, and - this is tke key - they are useless, because all the layouts of my `ListView`s
have const size.

So my question is: how to eliminate these calls? Of course I want to leave proper calls alone (caused by adding items to `Adapter` and `notifyDataSetChanged()` ).

I've tried almost anything, but either the whole list doesn't draw itself (when I overriden it's `onMeasure()` and forced to returned const size without calling `super.onMeasure()`) or stops updating at some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How you implemented the getView() method? If you implement it in the correct way there should be nearly no lagging.

Check out this really really good video:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70
- Slides: http://dl.google.com/googleio/2010/android-world-of-listview-android.pdf

As Romain said, work with it not against it. Best is to leave measure() alone and focus on your adapter.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll watch it but I don't think I can optimize my getView() method in any way. :/

Comment: Haven't found a good solution, but the thing which gave me most was a movie in your link - so I'll mark this as an answer.

Comment: Thanks, that video is amazingly useful (really good tips for speeding up getView). I've taken the liberty to fix the link (it was broken) and to add a link to the slides (for those who don't want to watch a full hour).

Answer (score 3):

Thats how **ListView** is implemented.. I don't think that will cause a performance Overhead.. Provided you do things properly there..

For example..

Don't instanciate `LayoutInflator` inside GetView Method, Do it at class level..

And Inflate View Only if the `convertView==null` or else just return `convertView`.. Inflating view is a costly process....

Comment: Ok, now I do it at the app level, but that gives me nothing, alas. Of course I do recycle views and try to avoid inflating as much as it's possible.

Comment: @FenixVoltres .. is there a problem you are facing..? or You are just trying to avoid multiple calss,,..

Comment: Problem is that I got lags (on one of the newest devices!) in my activity caused by enormous amount of `measure()` and `onMeasure()` calls on views inside adapters called (as I see it) in vain.

Answer (score 3):

Well like you said these calls are due to `measure()` and `onMeasure()` calls of `ListViews` parents and I'm sure you are using `height=wrap_content` also with `wrap_content` on height your `ListView` will check without stop if your height has changed.

**So the solution is**  to put the `height=fill_parent`.
I hope this helped you.

Comment: Damn, that is so right! Thanks a lot. I had 'wrap_content' and had the same problem. You saved me.

Answer (score 2):

The underlying reason for this is that `ListView.onMeasure()` calls `AbsListView.obtainView()`, which will request a view from your list adapter. So if your view is being remeasured through animations, your performance will be very poor.